# Display image from SD card to phone - JavaME

Tags: java, blackberry, java-me

I am trying to display an image from my SD card on my BlackBerry.

The code I have is this but nothing is showing on the BlackBerry screen.

```
InputStream input = filenames.openInputStream();
Image image=Image.createImage(input);
Image copy = Image.createImage(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight());            
javax.microedition.lcdui.Graphics g = copy.getGraphics();
g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, 0);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem might be with the fact you are creating an Image `copy` and trying to draw the `input` image onto that. Without knowing the rest of your code, it then seems like this image is never added onto your MainScreen object so is not displayed.

Is there any particular reason you are trying to do it this way?

You might be better using a `BitmapField` instead and explictly adding it to your MainScreen. Something like

```
    BitmapField imageCanvas = new BitmapField();

    InputStream input = photoFile.openInputStream();

    int fileSize = (int) photoFile.fileSize();
    byte[] data = new byte[fileSize];
    input.read(data, 0, fileSize);

    Bitmap photoBitmap = EncodedImage.createEncodedImage(data, 0, data.length).getBitmap();
    imageCanvas.setBitmap(photoBitmap);
    add(imageCanvas);
```

I've left out the `try catch` blocks for brevity